# Using just Spring Security CSRF feature

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

I'd like to use just the Spring Security's CSRF feature without any of the other authentication/authorization features since those features are provided by a third party provider for me. If this can be done, how do I tell Spring not to look out for any authentication  manager with its dependent beans and just intercept all URLs, and add the csrf token.

Comment: Did you try? What problem did you meet?

Answer (score 3):

I got the CSRF feature working by making the following changes/additions. Also, I used the `<form:form>` tag in my jsp to leverage the automatic insertion of the token by Spring.

jars added:

```
spring-security-acl-4.0.0.RC1.jar
spring-security-config-4.0.0.RC1.jar
spring-security-core-4.0.0.RC1.jar
spring-security-taglibs-4.0.0.RC1.jar
spring-security-web-4.0.0.RC1.jar
```

web.xml additions:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

New java file added:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class TgtWebSecurityConfigureAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Marco - With just the CSRF filter, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```

CSRF is enabled per default. You can than make use of (for example in thymeleaf):

```
<meta name="_csrf" value="dummy" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally avoid to include the Spring Security Filter chain if you intend to use only its CSRF protection. Without proper configuration, you will end up burdening your application with unnecessary logic.

The CSRF protection in Spring Security is offered by the `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter` servlet Filter.

By default the filter stores the expected CSRF token on the `HttpSession`.

You can easily implement something similar or attempt at declaring this filter only in your servlet filter chain / `web.xml`.